# Can we generate bearer token without calling its route ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

in normal case for getting **bearer token** we call its route that we defined in startup class ;

[image]

but i have a case that i need to generate this token in **Service layer** ;

i can do it with **REST** , but is there any solution to do it without using REST call ?

THANK_YOU_ALL ❤❤❤